# Is there a way to check if npm is installed properly since I got a lot of warnings during installation?

Tags: npm-install

I installed npm after installing node using the sudo command. I got it installed but got a lot of warnings. I ran npm audit fix next, since this was recommended. I am not sure now if it is installed properly. Version seems ok (8.4.1.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warnings are really not an issue, it is common.

The warnings may be showing Dependency warnings, Unsupported warnings. You don't have to worry about it.

If the warning is based on outdated dependencies you can run `ncu -u` to upgrade them automatically.

If you don't want to see the warnings while on an installation
use : `npm install --silent`